# Software for computing invariant rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

I have an linearly reductive algebraic group $G$ acting regularly on an affine variety $X$(over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0). I want to compute the invariant ring $\mathbb{K}[X]^{G}$. Now I don't expect to be able to find a software that can do this for any such $X$ and $G$, but I'm hoping I can find a software which can do it for some special cases.

I would be grateful if someone can suggest me what are those softwares and for what cases of $G$ and $X$ do they work.

Comment: Gregor Kemper has done a lot of work on these types of computations.  You're probably already familiar with his work; but, if you aren't, then that's where I'd start—specifically, with [Kemper et al. - A database of invariant rings](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1069855253).

Comment: I have used Singular for that very purpose, have a look at [rinvar_lib](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-3-2/sing_2095.htm#SEC2176)

Comment: Magma also has [Invariant theory package](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1343#14913) but you have to pay for it

Comment: Macaulay2 also has a package for this that I've used before.  http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.20/share/doc/Macaulay2/InvariantRing/html/